# Novel sugaring features in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, syntactic-sugar

I was reading [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060894/what-are-sugar-desugar-terms-in-context-of-java-8?noredirect=1#22060916). From the answers of that question I got sugaring concept and some examples of sugaring in `java 7`. 
I am  interested to know that is there any novel sugaring features which are added in `java 8` and not present in `java 7`?

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/features

Comment: i read question which is refereed in my question , from the answers of that previous question i did not get novel sugaring features which are added in java 8 , i commented on that question and someone suggest to put my question if I want answers.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the answer [here](http://ttux.net/post/java-8-new-features-release-performance-code/) which discusses all the new features of Java 8 including the syntactic sugar lambda expression:-

- Lambda expressions
- Remove the Permanent Generation
- Small VM
- Parallel Array Sorting
- Bulk Data Operations for Collections
- Define a standard API for Base64 encoding and decoding
- New Date & Time API
- Provide stronger Password-Based-Encryption (PBE) algorithm
  implementations in the SunJCE provider

Also check [Java 7 Features Which Enable Java 8](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-7-Features-Which-Enable-Java-8)

Comment: Read this.  Lambdas are NOT just syntactic sugar,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221659/java-8-lambda-expression-and-first-class-values

Comment: @StephenC:- Not trying to argure or contradict but this answer says that it is:- http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195081/is-a-lambda-expression-something-more-than-an-anonymous-inner-class-with-a-singl

Comment: @StephenC:- And I somewhat agree with the comment made by Phillip in that question:- `When a language is turing-complete, every added feature could theoretically be described as "syntactic sugar".`

Comment: You need to read the Answers more carefully.  For example, that one you linked to says *"**mostly** syntactic sugar"*.  Which is essentially what I'm saying, and what the link I provided says.

Comment: @StephenC:- Do correct me if I am wrong. So you mean that Lambda's are not syntactic sugars in Java?

Comment: No.  I mean what I said.  *"Lambdas are NOT just syntactic sugar"*.  See the word "just"?  I put it there because it is important to what I am saying.  (Consider these two statements:  "Barak Obama is not the President" and "Barak Obama is not just the President".  One of those statements is true, and the other is false.  The word "just" is the difference.)

Comment: @StephenC:- Got that! And yes perfect example to explain me the difference! Too good! Thanks again! +100